# How do I cancel a FirebaseObjectObservable subscription?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I know in other cases I can turn off an observable with unsubscribe() but as far as I can tell a FirebaseObjectObservable doesn't seem to have that function. How can I turn it off?

```
this.rock = this.af.database.object('/rocks/'+ rockKey);
this.rock.subscribe(obj=>{
  console.log("Can't stop the rock");
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't unsubscribe the observable; you unsubscribe the subscription. This has nothing to do with Firebase observables.

```
this.subscription = this.rock.subscribe(obj=>{
  console.log("Can't stop the rock");
});

this.subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: Ahhh, I've heard people say that but I didn't understand what they meant, I didn't realize I could save the subscription on it's own like that. Thank you!

Comment: i have an array , which is getting filled during subscription , but when i unsubscribe  , the array gets empty , why so ?

Comment: Something else must be going on, because unsubscribing could not possibly have any effect on some action taken in a subscription handler.

Comment: Sometimes subscription is undefined, any idea why?

Comment: If the `this.subscription =` line is executed, then `this.subscription` cannot be undefined. If it is undefined, it could only be because it was never assigned. If it's too much trouble to figure that out, then just write `if (this.subscription) this.subscription.unsubscribe();`.